# How should I use mysql_query?

Tags: php

I'm having some problems with this function in the next code:

```
if(!($_SESSION['autenticado']))
    if($_POST["user"] && $_POST["pass"])
    {
        $user=$_POST["user"];
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","3270");

            mysql_select_db("futbol",$con);
            $query = "SELECT us_pass FROM user WHERE us_nom = '$user'";
            print_r($query);
            mysql_real_escape_string($query);
            mysql_query($query)or die mysql_error();
            //print_r($pas);
            //$_SESSION["autenticado"]=1;
     }
```

Am I using it wrowng?

Comment: please tell us what the problem is. Do you get an error? What output are you expecting? What output are you receiving?

Comment: I'm not receiving any output, so strange. :S

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `mysql_real_escape_string` on the string that needs escaping, not the whole query:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$query = "SELECT us_pass FROM user WHERE us_nom = '$user'";
```

Addendum: if you are just exploring PHP's database integration, I'd urge you to have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), which is a far more sophisticated and secure way of handling database operations.

---

Note also that you're not actually doing anything with `mysql_query`.  This returns a resource, that you can then use to get information.  For example, to get the password returned, use the following:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $password = $row['us_pass'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's logic. 

But I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I know that I'm not doing nothing whith the output, that's because the mysql_query is doing nothing so I cannot continue. 

Thank you for the example.

Comment: @Vaul How do you know it's doing nothing? You're not assigning its result to anything.

Comment: It's only a supossition but I can't even see the html page, only a white background, no errors, no nothing.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, you are using it wrong, you want to call the escape function on just the input, not the entire query:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
```

That said, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should be using either [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Here's an example of a much better way to do it, using PDO:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:dbname=futbol;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '3270');
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT us_pass FROM user WHERE us_nom = :user');
$stmt->execute(array('user' => $user));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I don't think the `mysql_` functions are actually deprecated, but use of them is definitely discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string` Should be escaping `$user` before it's inserted in to the SQL query, then passed directly off to `mysql_query`. The purpose of this is to avoid `$_POST['user']` from having apostrophes in it that could otherwise foul up the query (since your user value is already surrounded in them.

e.g. if `$_POST['user']` had `joe'bob` as a value, your query would then become:

```
SELECT us_pass FROM user WHERE us_nom = 'joe'bob'
```

You can then see how a stray apostrophe could propose a problem.

Instead, try the following:

```
if(!($_SESSION['autenticado']))
  if($_POST["user"] && $_POST["pass"])
  {
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","3270");
    $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]); // escape your value here (and move below connection)

    mysql_select_db("futbol",$con);
    $query = "SELECT us_pass FROM user WHERE us_nom = '$user'";
    print_r($query);
    mysql_query($query) or die mysql_error();
    //print_r($pas);
    //$_SESSION["autenticado"]=1;

    // here you would mysql_fetch_array/result/etc. and get what
    // was returned from the database
 }
```

Comment: You can't call `mysql_real_escape_string` before you've opened a database connection.

Comment: @lonesomeday: touché. My primary focus was on query escaping and missed moving the process. Good catch, and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to the other answers: You are sending your form using `POST` and not `GET` right?

The only reasons that you're not seeing anything are your `if` conditions not being met, a problem connecting to the database or an error in your php (with errors suppressed); the script does not reach your `print_r` statement.

I´m not sure, but you also might want to use `{}` for your first `if` statement and clean-up your code a bit: I'd recommend `isset()` instead of just feeding strings to `if` statements.

And check your error log.

Comment: I solved it deleting the "or die mysql_error();" sentence, I can't explain it. I use ISSET() but, this code is only a bad correction of the first code caused by the many attemps to run it.

Thank you very much.